# Spring mongodb @DBRef query to search parent field in Basic Query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongoose

How can query mongodb to search all publications where author first name is "Vinod"?

Here is my Publication Class

```
@Document(collection = "publications")
public class Publication {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String title;

    private Date publicationDate;

    @DBRef
    private Author author;

    //getter and setters here
}
```

And my author class is

```
@Document(collection = "authors")
public class Author {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String username;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    //getter and setters here
}
```

This is how it is stored in the database.

Publication

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a339cc4e193d31c47916c2c"),
   "_class" : "com.publication.models.Publication",
  "title" : "Some title",
  "publicationDate" : ISODate("2017-12-15T09:58:28.617Z"),
  "author" : {
    "$ref" : "authors",
    "$id" : ObjectId("5a339cc0e193d31c47916ad0")
  }
}
```

And author:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a339cc0e193d31c47916ad0"),
  "_class" : "com.publication.models.Author",
  "username" : "abcd0050",
  "firstName" : "Vinod",
  "lastName" : "Kumar"
}
```

This is how I need to query.

```
BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery("{ author.name : 'vinod' }");
Publication test = mongoOperation.find(query, Publication.class);
```

Comment: How are you querying? using spring-data repository ?

Comment: @pvpkiran - Updated question with query.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Query query = Query.query(new Criteria("author.name", "vinod"));
Publication test = mongoOperation.find(query, Publication.class);
```

You could also do

```
BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery().addCriteria(new Criteria("author.name", "vinod"))
```

Comment: I have not tested this but I not looking for spring query builder. I need to build query using BasicQuery class as I am using Jquery Query builder at frontend. http://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html

Comment: BasicQuery is a subclass of Query.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest RelMongo for you which is a little framework built on top of Spring Data to allow using @OneToMany and @OneToOne annotations with MongoDB collections in a JPA Way